# Xref Net Labels in eagle

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I'm trying to make a shield for `Arduino` in `Eagle`.
I connected a floating NET from my shield pin and labeled it as for example `PIN5` and marked it as `XRef`
But on `ERC` I'm getting **`Only INPUT pins on net PIN5`** and **`Only one pin on net PIN5`**
Here is and image of it:
[image]

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: When you define a component symbol you can decide the net state of each pin e.g - in, out, in/out, tristate, pwr. This determines what ERC flags comes up. You can probably ignore it if its the only issue and you don't want to deal with untangling the pin properties

Comment: @crasic: Thanks but this is for `Only INPUT pins on net PIN5`; what abount `Only one pin on net PIN5` ?

Comment: @4riy4n An "INPUT" Pin needs something to drive it, so ERC is complaining that there is a lack of "OUTPUT" pin on the same net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only INPUT pins on net PIN5

This error is caused by pin 14 of IC6 being labelled as an INPUT pin. The ERC has noticed that there is no corresponding OUTPUT pin connected to the PIN5 net, so it believes there is an error. Since you are building an arduino shield, you can safely ignore this error.

> Only one pin on net PIN5

Eagle is saying that it sees a net, called PIN5, that has only one thing connected to it. This error should not be ignored. Without seeing the rest of the schematic, it's hard to tell what the cause of this error is. But I'd guess that you have not added the shield's mating connectors (or have not labelled the connector's pins). Once you add the mating connector to the schematic and connect the corresponding pin to the PIN5 net, that error will go away.